# cumulative divide in array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy 1D array

```
l = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

I want to divide each element by last element of array.

```
l = [0.11 0.33 0.55 0.66 0.88 1]
```

is there any method like cummulative divide in numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there's a cumulative divide method, but this should do it:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9], dtype=np.float)
>>> a/a[-1]
array([ 0.11111111,  0.33333333,  0.55555556,  0.66666667,  0.88888889,  1.        ])
```